# CI/CD implementation on database

Tags: database, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2017 and I want to implement CI/CD using Jenkins.
If I am making the proc changes or changing the name of column in my dev database, I want those changes to be reflecting in the QA database after I push my dev database changes.

I am aware about red gate but I don't want to use it. Looking to implement it without using any paid software.

Answer (score 0):

Redgate (who I work for) offers [Flyway Community](https://flywaydb.org/), which is a free tier. This employs a migrations-based model in which you author each change as a SQL migration script. You then invoke [Flyway migrate](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/commandline/migrate) (its command line) from Jenkins to intelligently apply the migration scripts to the various environments managed by your Jenkins pipeline.